# No such field exception while loading "scl" field from Classloader

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader, java-12

I am moving my code from JDK 8 to Open JDK 12. While doing so, I am facing following issue :

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: scl

while trying to call ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("scl"). This was working fine in Java 8 but no longer works in newer Java versions.

I did some findings and believe it has got to do with the way working of reflection and use of internal Java packages have changed since Java 8.

```
Set<URL> classLoaderUrls = computeClassLoaderUrls();
            ClassLoader bootstrapClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent();
            this.classLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls.toArray(new URL[classLoaderUrls.size()]), bootstrapClassLoader);


            Field systemClassLoaderField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("scl");
            systemClassLoaderField.setAccessible(true);
            this.initialSystemClassLoader = (ClassLoader) systemClassLoaderField.get(null);
            systemClassLoaderField.set(null, this.classLoader);
```

I want to know , if the way to access these `classloader` and its fields has changed or should I use some other field instead of `scl`. Thanks

Comment: ClassLoader's private fields are hidden from introspection for security reasons. In any case, it's way to fragile and dangerous to be hacking these fields directly. The supported way to override the system class loader is to run with the system property java.system.class.loader set on the command line (ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader's javadoc has all the details).

Comment: @AlanBateman Thanks Alan, Could you please suggest how to override the system class loader property from command line. Basically , I am using the class loading to start tomcat server for my application.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the system class loader? Just use your custom class loader.

Comment: I am adding my loaded URLClassloader in the systemClassloader. Basically the code following this one,  starts a tomcat server which is failing in new JDK. The Tomcat is not able to find the dependencies if I remove these lines of code (modification in the systemclassloader).